# Nested flexbox does not shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get a variable number of square images to fill up a parent container. I need the images to grow or shrink in size *responsive* to ensure that they all fit, but never expand beyond the size of the the parent container horizontally *and* vertically. Image ratio also needs to be preserved without cropping.

I am trying to use nested flex-boxes to accomplish this. The `.outer-flex-container` is working as expected with everything shrinking/growing along the horizontal axis while maintaining the aspect ratio.

With the `.inner-flex-container` I am trying to get the same results, but along the vertical axis (`flex-flow: column`). However when you shrink the container size, you get images that do not shrink (or distort the aspect ratio).

I have read through numerous posts about using `min-height: 0` to override the default `min-height: auto` however this does not seem to solve my problem.

Why does the `.inner-flex-container` not shrink to the size of the container? Is there a better approach than flexbox to accomplish this?

```css
.outer-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
}

.outer-flex-container:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.outer-flex-child {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.inner-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  /* max-height: 100%;  <-- Distorts aspect ratio */
  /* max-width: 100%; <-- Distorts aspect ratio */
}

.inner-flex-child {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-flex-container">
  <div class="outer-flex-child">
    <div class="inner-flex-container">
      <img class="inner-flex-child" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH01k.png' />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer-flex-child">
    <div class="inner-flex-container">
      <img class="inner-flex-child" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH01k.png' />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/tj27rLw1/

Comment: Yes, that does look like it what I am going for. So, it looks like I needed to make the .outer-flex-child a flex container with .inner-flex-container as its child flex item?  Or in other words, I mistakenly only had 2 levels of nesting when I needed 3 levels? (Thanks for your help)

Comment: Have added answer below with explanations, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest flexboxes a bit more:

- make your `outer-flex-child` a *flexbox* too and add `flex: 0 1 auto` to its *flex item* (`inner-flex-container`).
- and because your `inner-flex-container` is a *column flexbox* add `align-items: flex-start` to *override* the default *stretch* beahvior (`align-items: stretch`) that breaks the aspect ratio of the image flex item.

See demo below:

```css
.outer-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
}

.outer-flex-container:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.outer-flex-child {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex; /* added */
}

.inner-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto; /* added */
  align-items: flex-start; /* added */
}

.inner-flex-child {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-flex-container">
  <div class="outer-flex-child">
    <div class="inner-flex-container">
      <img class="inner-flex-child" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH01k.png' />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer-flex-child">
    <div class="inner-flex-container">
      <img class="inner-flex-child" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH01k.png' />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```